# Regex including unwated digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create an expression to collect anything but digits and the character `*`. I tried to use the expression `\D[^*]` but somehow it's retrieving the first digit after blank espaces. I tried this expression with the string `1234 1234 1234 ****` and the matches were: ' 1', ' 1'. Can anyone tell me why would the expression collect the digits with the blank spaces?

Thank you.

Comment: Your regex is asking to match something that is not a digit, followed by something that is not a `*`. So it matches `' 1'` because that is a non-digit (space) followed by a non-* (1)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  may be wrong but  I suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/180121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex (`'\D[^*]'`) will match a Space (thats' not a digit) followed by a digit (that's not a star '*').

You can do several Things, the easiest is to include '\d' in the character Group, then it will Work, because both `'\d'` and `'*'` are excluded:

```
/[^\d*]/g
```

Now it will only match `Spaces` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

A square brackets in regex are a set, and a square bracket with ^ mean not in set.
The \d should also be inside the brackets:

```
[^\d*]
```

https://regex101.com/r/WizvVh/1